# When Android Service code in a Google Play app will be updated?

Tags: java, android, google-play, android-service

I have an Android app published on Google Play. When the app is launched for the first time (it is done by storing and checking boolean flag `"FirstLaunch"` in `SharedPreferences`), it launches a `Service` which will be launched once a day (=every 24 hours using `AlarmManager`).
For the sake of simplicity let's say that this service just shows a `Toast` with `"Hello World!"` when the time comes.
Let's assume that there is a user who downloaded and installed my app from Google Play.
Let's also assume that I have changed some code in that service (e.g. changed the `Toast` from `"Hello World"` to `"Hello Universe!"`) and updated the app on Google Play.
If that user updates my app, will the service start showing new `Toast` text (`"Hello Universe"`) once a day, or will it still show the old version (`"Hello World"`)?
Generally speaking, if I am changing the code of a running service, do I need to relaunch it programmatically in my app, or will Android itselft change/switch its code to the new version?

Comment: I think when you Replace the older with newer(update) then your app also to be updated. but you have to start your `Service` again.

Answer (score 0):

If Android updates an app (through the PlayStore of course),which you are currently using, it gets terminated. Services get terminated as well. So if users of your app receive their update, their service gets terminated and restarted, if the`startmode`of your service is`sticky` or it gets restarted by your app.

Answer (score 0):

Android services runs as part of your application process, when the process is terminated your services will be terminated as well (it will be restarted if its start mode is sticky which will restart the whole process), so when the user updates your app a new process will be started with your new code